# SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius) results in "unrecognized selector sent to class" in Playground for OSX

Tags: sprite-kit, swift, swift-playground

The following playground results in a timeline error "unrecognized selector sent to class..."

```
import SpriteKit
let node = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 10)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPK5J.png)

Seems to work ok when platform is iOS.
Running 10.9.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because you're running it on an OS X version that's older than the API you're trying to use. The code you're using requires OS X 10.10, or iOS 8 and up.

The [OS X 10.10 API Differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/General/Reference/APIDiffsMacOSX10_10SeedDiff/index.html) confirm that all of SKShapeNodes custom initializers have just been added in 10.10. Previously, all we could do with SKShapeNode, was initialize an instance, and then modify its `path` property.

Comment: I have a similar error I think, but mine is present from the beggining of a project, when I use the Mac Game Template. I launch it and it prints _"2014-08-09 20:50:21.294 PokemonSK[3808:303] +[PokemonSK.GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100009150
2014-08-09 20:50:21.295 PokemonSK[3808:303] +[PokemonSK.GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10000915"_       **Is it the same thing and how can I solve it without upgrading to Yosemite ?**

Comment: "Available in iOS 8.0 and later."
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKShapeNode/shapeNodeWithCircleOfRadius:

Comment: I am running OSX 10.10 with xCode 6.1 and still get the error

Comment: @AdamSmith something else must be wrong. Can you show what code causes this? Are you importing SpriteKit?

Comment: This is happening for me as well. On OS X 10.10.1. For both iOS and OS X platforms.

Comment: @0x7fffffff XCode 6.1.