# OSX SpriteKit Game template in Swift not working - XCode6-b5

Tags: macos, templates, swift, sprite-kit

Well, that's odd: I wanted to try creating a little Mac Game using Swift and Xcode6-b5, but when I open the a new project template, and without changing ANYTHING, the GameScene isn't loaded and the console shows these two lines when I try to run it:

```
2014-08-09 20:50:21.294 PokemonSK[3808:303] +[PokemonSK.GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100009150
2014-08-09 20:50:21.295 PokemonSK[3808:303] +[PokemonSK.GameScene nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x100009150
```

I saw similar topics like this one [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127212/skshapenodecircleofradius-results-in-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-class-in) but they don't explain how to fix it, and i don't want to upgrade to Yosemite...

**Has anybody an idea to solve this ?**

Thanks

(here is the AppDeleguate code, it might help)

```
import Cocoa
import SpriteKit

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

@IBOutlet var window: NSWindow!
@IBOutlet var skView: SKView!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    /* Pick a size for the scene */
    let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
    /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
    scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

    self.skView!.presentScene(scene)

    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    self.skView!.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

}

func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true;
```

Comment: did apple also release a new beta of osx at the same time? if so you may need to install that too

Comment: Ok, so it's not just me having this...

Comment: So, if this does only work on 10.10, what does that mean for us if we want to target a wider variety of machines? Should we expect Apple to release a new SpriteKit for older OSs, or are we going to have to strip out all this code by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is apparently adding new APIs and using them before they are widely available. This is more annoying than it should be, especially as the code in question doesn't really add anything.

You can get the basic demo code working with a single change. Look for:

```
    let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene")
```

In the AppDelegate.swift file, and change that to:

```
    let scene = GameScene(size:self.skView.bounds.size)
```

Comment: Oh, and another bug, this time in the documentation: /* Pick a size for the scene */ doesn't actually do that, it's picking a background image.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if it is the same thing but I experienced a similar issue trying to run a project from beta 5 on an iOSdevice.

Rather than

```
let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")
```

try

```
if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene {
....
}
```

with a function unarchiveFromFile, which I think came in earlier templates.

```
extension SKNode {
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {

    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks")

    var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
    var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)

    archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
    let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as GameScene
    archiver.finishDecoding()
    return scene
}
```

}

Comment: I tried but this errors came out: "GameScene.Type' does not have a member named 'unarchiveFromFile'" :/

Comment: You likely put the second part of his code in the wrong place. Cut and paste it so it's immediately after the last line of your AppDelegate.swift. And you also have to make the setup line like...         scene?.scaleMode = .AspectFill

Answer (score 0):

FYI everyone, this problem has been fixed in B6. Now the solution noted above will cause linker errors instead. Be sure to *remove* your unarchiveFromFile and revert the original code to use fileNamed:. Somewhat annoying, especially given the error is so opaque.